# How to add id to element if body contains certain class and an element id contains a class

Tags: javascript, magento, magento-1.9

The following code would assign the class "active" to the element with id="39". That would happen if two conditions are met: 1) That the body contains "hotel-stores" in its class -so the body class might be hotel-stores, hotel-stores-1, hotel-stores-2, hotel-stores-3, etc.- and 2) that the element with id="dropdown-menu" would contain the class "active".

Still, the code does not work. Do you have any ideas where the errors is, or why this code does not work?

```
if ( ($('body[class*="hotel-stores"]').length > 0)  && ( $( "#dropdown-menu" ).is( ".active" ) ))  {
   var el = document.getElementById("39");
   el.classList.add("active");
}
```

This second way seems to work pretty well, but only when the body class is 'hotel-stores':

```
if (document.body.classList.contains('hotel-stores')) {
    var el = $(document.getElementById("39"));
    el.addClassName("active");
}
```

Comment: Provided the elements exist and have those classes as of when that code is run, it works: https://jsfiddle.net/ugtv8uL0/ Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Hi T.J. I tested it and there is a mention showing up: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at hotel-stores; probably that's the issue by which it does not work. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In a comment you've said

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null at hotel-stores

That tells me that `$` in that code is not jQuery, as [I assumed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50101180/javascript-in-magento-1-9-3-8-add-id-to-element-if-body-contains-certain-class?noredirect=1#comment87219029_50101180), but some other library, probably [PrototypeJS](http://prototypejs.org/) given it's a Magento site.

If you *also* have jQuery loaded, just change all of the `$` to `jQuery` and it should work.

If you aren't also loading jQuery, you can do the same thing with PrototypeJS, just slightly differently because PrototypeJS isn't set-based like jQuery is:

```
if (document.body.className.indexOf('hotel-stores') !== -1 && $$("#dropdown-menu.active").length) {
   var el = $(document.getElementById("39"));
   el.addClassName("active");
}
```

Comment: Hi T.J. The Uncaught TypeError is no longer to see, but the element with id="39" does not get the class="active" yet; do you have more tips?

Comment: @Eduardo: The code above [works](https://jsfiddle.net/ugtv8uL0/1/) with PrototypeJS, so if you're not seeing the class added, then either `body` doesn't have the relevant class, `#dropdown-menu` doesn't have the relevant class, you copied the code incorrectly, or your page isn't using PrototypeJS.

Comment: Hi T.J. I have updated the code (second way); this seems to work well, but only when the category is 'hotel-stores'; do you know a way to adjust this 'second way' code, in a way that any class starting with 'hotel-stores' would be also be taken into account in the code?

Comment: @Eduardo: `document.body.className.indexOf('hotel-stores') !== -1` will definitely be true regardless of where `hotel-stores` appears in the element's class attribute, whether part of another class or not.